# gradle7.2 How to introduce LeakCanary plugins

Tags: gradle

buildscript {
dependencies {
classpath 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-deobfuscation-gradle-plugin:${version}'
}
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVjcr.png)

A problem occurred evaluating root project '��д��'.

> plugin id 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-deobfuscation-gradle-plugin' is invalid: Plugin id contains invalid char ':' (only ASCII alphanumeric characters, '.', '_' and '-' characters are valid)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the plugin incorrectly. The plugin ID is different than the artifact GAV.

https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/#using-leakcanary-with-obfuscated-apps

An updated example:

`settings.gradle.kts`

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    resolutionStrategy.eachPlugin {
        if (requested.id.id == "com.squareup.leakcanary.deobfuscation") {
            useModule("com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-deobfuscation-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("com.squareup.leakcanary.deobfuscation") version "2.8.1"
}
```

Comment: build.gradle？  how should it be achieved

Comment: Syntax is the same for this example.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at curtains.internal.WindowCallbackWrapper$Companion.getJetpackWrapped(:112)
        at curtains.internal.WindowCallbackWrapper$Companion.unwrap(:154)
        at curtains.WindowsKt.getWrappedCallback(:233)
        at leakcanary.RootViewWatcher$listener$1.onRootViewAdded(:46)
        at curtains.OnRootViewAddedListener$DefaultImpls.onRootViewsChanged(:38)
        at leakcanary.RootViewWatcher$listener$1.onRootViewsChanged(:43)
        at curtains.internal.RootViewsSpy$delegatingViewList$1.add(:25)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367145/android-leakcanary-obfuscate-plugin-error